# Indefinite integral $ \int \cos x \sqrt{\cos2x}dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

$$
\int \cos x \sqrt{\cos2x}dx
$$

I know that $\cos 2x = 1-2\sin^2x,$ but not sure if it will help me?

Integrate by parts?

$$
\sin x \sqrt{1-2\sin^{2}x}-\int \sin x \frac{-\sin2x}{\sqrt{\cos2x}}dx
$$
This doesn't seem to get me anywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: write $\cos2x = 1 - 2\sin^2 x$, and let $u = \sin xdx$, then $du = \cos xdx$. You can take it from here.